# Column with number of versions in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheet with data validation to generate autocomplete cells. Does anyone know how you can generate the following in a column:

```
1.0.0
1.0.1
1.0.2
......
56.2.3
```

is to then look for the correct version from the main sheet.

Comment: what follows after 1.0.9 ??? 1.0.10 or 1.1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B); 1; 100)&""; "(.{1})(.{1}$)"; ".$1.$2"))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, neither in excel 2013 nor in google sheet

Comment: @Max both provided formula are for Google Sheets

Comment: Excellent! It's true! in google sheet it works perfectly!
A query, and if I wanted to make that after 1.0.9 continue with 1.0.10, 1.0.11 like this until 1.0.99?
In the case of adding one more digit, how would it be? for example 1.0.2.15?
Thanks since now!

Comment: @Max see https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K34J.png & https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuOjL.png

Comment: Unfortunately = Array does not work on google sheet, = Index function does.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B))/100)&"."&
 RIGHT(ROUNDDOWN((SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B))-1)/10), 1)&"."&
 RIGHT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B2:B))-1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, neither in excel 2013 nor in google sheet

Comment: Unfortunately = Array does not work on google sheet, = Index function does.
https://i.imgur.com/L2gQO4u.jpeg

Comment: Investigating a bit I see that it is about the language, I adapted the code and it looks like this:
https://i.imgur.com/GPELU6Y.jpeg